# How do I open links to a specific website in a non-default browser on a Mac?

Tags: google-chrome, pivotal-tracker

My default browser is the latest Chrome on the latest OS X. I want to open links to pivotaltracker.com (from Skype, email, wherever) in a Fluid browser that is dedicated to Pivotal Tracker. Googling got me nothing useful.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you need [Choosy](http://www.choosyosx.com/), which will let you do exactly this sort of thing.

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to vote this up but this worked perfectly. Fluid still insists on opening a new window/tab but I don't think there is really any way around that.

Comment: Just glad I could help. But I thought you can accept the answer anyway, since you've asked the question?